# Scripting bzr commands

Tags: bash, python, bazaar

Can someone push me in the right direction to either use a shell script or Python to make a script to simplify pushing a bzr branch to launchpad?

The script process would be simple:

1. `cd /directory/to/code`
2. ask for commit comment
3. `bzr commit - m $comment`
4. `bzr push lp:~path/to/code`

Answer (score 2):

You could put this in a script almost as it is...

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cd /directory/to/code
bzr commit
bzr push
```

I ommitted the `-m` for `bzr commit` intentionally. Bazaar will start the configured text editor where you can enter it, no need to "ask for it".

I also omitted `lp:~path/to/code` intentionally. After you do a `bzr push lp:~path/to/code` once manually, Bazaar will remember that location and next time it's enough to do simply `bzr push`.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts are pretty easy to start with. The first line must be `#!/bin/sh` (a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) — just copy-paste). Then put one command per line.

If you want the script to stop if a command fails, add the line `set -e` as the second line.

If you're debugging a script and want to display the commands it's executing just before they're executed, add `set -x` as the second line.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /directory/to/code
bzr commit
bzr push lp:~path/to/code
```

The best way to “ask for commit comment” is to open an editor for you to enter it. That's what `bzr commit` does.

Save this file in the directory `~/bin` (create it if it doesn't exist) and give it execution permissions (`chmod +x ~/bin/push-my-code` on the command line).

If you invoke this script from a command line, then typically you'd already be in the right directory, so you wouldn't need the `cd` command first. Rather than a script, in that case, you might add a function to your `.bashrc`:

```
commit-and-push () {
  bzr commit &&
  bzr push lp:~path/to/code
}
```

Then typing `commit-and-push` will run the two commands `bzr commit` and `bzr push`. The `&&` sign at the end of the first command means that the next command isn't executed if the first command fails (so if you notice you made a mistake while typing the changelog entry and cancel the commit then nothing will be pushed). If you always push to the same place, leave off the argument to the push command — just `bzr commit` then `bzr push` is enough.